# Difference between Genus, Genus sp. and Genus spp

Tags: taxonomy

What is the difference between the three following sentences?

- There is significant increase in *Bifidobacterium*
- There is significant increase in *Bifidobacterium sp.*
- There is significant increase in *Bifidobacterium spp.*

Of course, this could be applied to any genus.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species#Abbreviations

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia:

[Books and articles sometimes intentionally do not identify species fully and use the abbreviation "sp." in the singular or "spp." (standing for species pluralis, the Latin for multiple species) in the plural in place of the specific name or epithet (e.g. Canis sp.) This commonly occurs when authors are confident that some individuals belong to a particular genus but are not sure to which exact species they belong, as is common in paleontology. Authors may also use "spp." as a short way of saying that something applies to many species within a genus, but not to all. If scientists mean that something applies to all species within a genus, they use the genus name without the specific name or epithet. The names of genera and species are usually printed in italics. Abbreviations such as "sp." should not be italicised. When a species identity is not clear a specialist may use "cf." before the epithet to indicate that confirmation is required. The abbreviations "nr." (near) or "aff." (affine) may be used when the identity is unclear but when the species appears to be similar to the species mentioned after.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species#Abbreviations)